# showing selections from drop downs in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

i have set of drop downs with a select button below.
what i want to try to do is once the user has been through the three drop downs and pressed select, the option that is chosen is shown in a corresponding table in its assigned category

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
<select  name='first' id='first'>
    <option selected="selected" value="nothing">choose</option>   
    <option value='opt_a'>opt a</option>
    <option value='opt_b'>opt b</option>
</select>
<select name='sec' id='sec'>
</select>
<select name='third' id='third'>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<button id="select_btn" type="select" name="select">select</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="result">
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>category</td>
       <th>choice</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
       <td>choice 1</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 2</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 3</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 4</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
       <td>choice 5</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 6</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 7</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>choice 8</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
data = {
opt_a: ['choose_1','choose_2','choose_3','choose_4'],
opt_b: ['choose_5','choose_6','choose_7','choose_8'],
choose_1: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_2: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_3: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_4: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_5: ['a','b','avg','unclear'],
choose_6: ['a','b','avg','unclear'],
choose_7: ['a','b','avg','unclear'],
choose_8: ['a','b','avg','unclear']
}

$('#first').change(function(){
var firstopts = ''
$.each(data[$(this).val()],function(i,v){
    firstopts += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</option>"
}) 
$('#sec').html(firstopts)
})


$('#sec').change(function(){
var secopts = ''
$.each(data[$(this).val()],function(i,v){
    secopts += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</option>"
}) 
$('#third').html(secopts)
})
```

CSS:

```
select{width:150px;}

#result{width:450px; border:2px solid #234323;}

td{width:225px; text-align:center}

th{background:#656454; color:#eee; text-align:center}
```

Thank You in advance for any help.

Comment: You seem to have most of it figured out. What is causing you trouble? (how to "remember" the previously selected values, how to update the table, something else...)

Comment: How to actually show the option selected in the table? For example; for choose_7 the user selects 'avg'. once the `#select_btn` button is pressed i want to show 'avg' next to choice 7 on the table. And with each choice the table is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `data` keys are called `choose_N` and your columns have the text `choice N`, you can match them by splitting the value and getting the last part:

```
var number1 = 'choose_1'.split('_')[1];
var number2 = 'choice 1'.split(' ')[1];
return number1 == number2; // corresponding choice
```

You could also annotate your HTML with the corresponding value, if you want something more exact:

```
<tr data-choice="choose_1">
   <td>choice 1</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>

$(myselector).data("choice"); // Will return "choose_1"
```

Now all you have to do is to select the right row (the one that corresponds to the value currently selected in `#sec`) and set the second column to the value currently selected in `#third`. You could do it on the `click` callback of the select button, but a better option is to do it on `$('#third').change` directly (so the user is saved from one extra button press):

```
$('#third').change(function() {
    $('table tr').filter(function() {                                // Filters the rows, by:
        var number1 = $('#sec').val().split('_')[1];                 // comparing the value at #sec
        var number2 = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().split(' ')[1]; // with the text of the first column.
        return number1 == number2;
    }).find('td:eq(1)').text($(this).val()); // Updates the second column.
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8HfHm/) at jsFiddle. The only caveat is that, if the user wants to select the first option (the one already selected), he'll have to change it and change again for the event to trigger (in this sense, a `select` button is cleaner).

if you still want to do that only on button press, just replace `$('#third').change(...)` with `$('#select_btn').click(...)` (*Edit:* and `$(this)` to `$('#third')`). You might also have to use `event.preventDefault`, so the form isn't submitted.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks for the help. My jquery/js knowledge is still a little fresh, i was thinking of assigning the `data-attr`, but wasn't sure. Two extra things, how would i (1)get the dropdowns to reset once the select button is clicked and (2) the best way to save this table data so when the user logs in, they can view their choices?

Comment: To reset, just empty the selects (i.e. remove all `option`s): `$('#sec, #third').empty()`; to save between logins, that will depend - client side or server side? ajax or form submit? what you're using in the server? etc. That can't be reasonably answered here.

Comment: the user login system will be server side, but for this user input i was looking to have it client side/server(no database), possibly with the aid of ajax/json. I was looking to design it with a save and edit buttons, so the user (1) enter their choices, (2) presses save upon completion. (3) And that those choices would be displayed  in the table. (4) If they wish to edit them they could press the 'edit' button. (5) And saving it would create a new JSON/txt file. Am i on the right track or is that not possible?

Comment: @user1648449 looks fine to me. To send the values to the server (or to retrieve them and update the table) you can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Now, it's your choice if you want to keep those values in the markup itself, in [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) structures, or in JavaScript variables (any will do, choose according to your personal preferences).

Comment: thanks for the help and advice. one quick question about my drop downs, i was just noticing how when i click for example 'opt a', the second drop down shows 'choose_1', which is fine but in order to view 'choose_1' choices i have to click another choose_# then go back to it, to open the third drop down. Is there any way to have the first choose_# have its choices(third drop down) open automatically?

Comment: The easiest way IMHO is to trigger the `change` event: `$('#first').change(function() { ... $('#sec').html(firstopts).trigger('change') })`.

Comment: Excellent. I was thinking of something much more complicated. Thanks for all the help again.